# Immediatly persist in H2 database with spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I using H2 database in memory for test. And I have problem with non identical behavior PostgreSQL and H2.

This is simple code

```
        System.out.println("BEFORE:");
        List<FirstTable> values = myDAO.findAll(FirstTable.class);
        values.forEach(System.out::println);

        FirstTable ft = new FirstTable();
        ft.setValue("added value");
        myDAO.save(ft);

        System.out.println("AFTER SAVE:");
        System.out.println(ft);

        System.out.println("TABLE RESULT");
        List<FirstTable> values2 = myDAO.findAll(FirstTable.class);
        values2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

and outputs with pg and h2

```
pg
BEFORE:
id: 1; value: 1234
id: 2; value: 2345
id: 3; value: 3456
id: 4; value: 4567
AFTER SAVE:
id: 5; value: added value
TABLE RESULT:
id: 1; value: 1234
id: 2; value: 2345
id: 3; value: 3456
id: 4; value: 4567
id: 5; value: added value

h2
BEFORE:
id: 1; value: 1234_test
id: 2; value: 2345_test
id: 3; value: 3456_test
id: 4; value: 4567_test
AFTER SAVE:
id: 5; value: added value
TABLE RESULT:
id: 1; value: 1234_test
id: 2; value: 2345_test
id: 3; value: 3456_test
id: 4; value: 4567_test
```

So as we can se id for ft was assigned in both tries, but find in case with h2 was without new entry.

h2 properties for test:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from '../src/main/resources/my_dump.sql'
spring.datasource.user=sa
spring.datasource.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

MyDaoImpl save realization:

```
    public void save(MyEntity entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
```

UDPATE:
Full output in test:

```
> Task :common:compileJava
> Task :app:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processTestResources
> Task :app:testClasses
> Task :common:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :common:classes
> Task :common:jar UP-TO-DATE
2024-01-12T11:57:24.032+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] WorkersTest                              : Starting WorkersTest using Java 17.0.9 with PID 151062 (started by ilys in /home/ilys/Programming/learn/testHibernate/app)
2024-01-12T11:57:24.035+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] WorkersTest                              : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-12T11:57:24.255+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-01-12T11:57:24.270+03:00  WARN 151062 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.a.AutoConfigurationPackages        : @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the default package. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is not enabled.
2024-01-12T11:57:24.271+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-01-12T11:57:24.446+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-01-12T11:57:24.472+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.3.1.Final
2024-01-12T11:57:24.489+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-01-12T11:57:24.592+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-01-12T11:57:25.037+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-01-12T11:57:25.058+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-12T11:57:25.357+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [    Test worker] WorkersTest                              : Started WorkersTest in 1.459 seconds (process running for 1.915)
BEFORE:
id: 1; value: 1234_test
id: 2; value: 2345_test
id: 3; value: 3456_test
id: 4; value: 4567_test
AFTER SAVE:
id: 5; value: added value
TABLE RESULT
id: 1; value: 1234_test
id: 2; value: 2345_test
id: 3; value: 3456_test
id: 4; value: 4567_test
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2024-01-12T11:57:25.837+03:00  INFO 151062 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> Task :app:test
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
7 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 4 up-to-date
11:57:25: Execution finished ':app:test --tests "WorkersTest.sometest"'.
```

So is there possible to make persist behavior for pf and h2 the same? Where is my mistake?

Comment: It might not even be related to the difference of using H2 vs Postgres, but the way transactions are handled in your test. Can you show us how you bootstrap your application in your test?

Comment: @g00glen00b I updated my question. added all output in test.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a FirstTable.java mistake.
Add a @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) above the "id" line.

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

Comment: it ruins both: test and app. In both cases I've got mistake sequence not found. Although in pg I have auto configured seq. relation "first_table_seq" does not exist; pg made first_table_id_seq. Your solution is not suitable